# How to make TwoWay Binding work

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have this problem when I put the `Binding Mode` to `TwoWay` the `DataGrid` won't show. When I leave the `Binding Mode` as it is on default, the `DataGrid` will apear as `strings`, and I cannot find the problem.
In `XAML` I have 3 more `button`s: `Load`(that loads the table), `Update` and `Cancel`(that cancel all the changes and reloads the `DataGrid` directly from `ObservableCollection`.

Here is my `XAML` `DataGrid` line

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGreen" Height="245" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Userss.GetValues, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

I have a `Userss` `Class` where i creat my `ObservableCollection` where i store the data from my `SQLite` `database`.

```
public class Userss : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static SQLiteConnection m_dd = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");

    public static ObservableCollection<Userss> userCol = new ObservableCollection<Userss>();
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Sex _sex;
    public Sex Sex
    {
        get { return _sex; }
        set
        {
            _sex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Stations _station;
    public Stations Station
    {
        get { return _station; }
        set
        {
            _station = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Jobs _job;
    public Jobs Job
    {
        get { return _job; }
        set
        {
            _job = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Userss> GetValues()
    {
        m_dd.Open();
        string sql = "select * from user";
        userCol.Clear();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dd);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string sex1 = reader["sex"].ToString();
            string station1 = reader["station"].ToString();
            string job1 = reader["job"].ToString();
            string data1 = reader["date"].ToString();
            userCol.Add(new Userss()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                Sex = (Sex)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sex), sex1),
                Station = (Stations)Enum.Parse(typeof(Stations), station1),
                Job = (Jobs)Enum.Parse(typeof(Jobs), job1),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(data1)
            });
        }
        m_dd.Close();
        return userCol;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }
}

public enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female
}
public enum Jobs
{
    Programmer,
    Designer,
    Manager,
    CTO,
    CEO,
}
public enum Stations
{
    Desktop,
    Laptop,
    Tablet
}
```

}

And here is my implementation for my `MainWindow`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SQLiteConnection m_db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    SQLiteDataAdapter adap;
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt;
    SQLiteCommandBuilder cmdbl;
    string Query;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            m_db.Open();
            ObservableCollection<Userss> cUser = Userss.GetValues();
            Query = "Select * from user";
            adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, m_db);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Users");
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGrid.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            m_db.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to make those changes?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
                adap.Update(ds, "Users");
                ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
                dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            this.dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }

    private void CancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel those changes?", "Please confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Userss.GetValues();
        }
        else
            this.dataGrid.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

}

Btw I work in `WPF`.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `TwoWay`-Binding doesn't make much sense when you are binding to a function. Why don't you just bind to your `userCol`-Collection instead?

Comment: I've tryed it, that's why i declared it outside the function. The result is the same nothing happens.

Comment: Setting `Mode=TwoWay` never makes sense for a Binding on the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl. Besides that, you can't bind to a method (like your `GetValues`). You can only bind to a public property, Here you could perhaps declare a static Users property. Note also that you are replacing the ItemsSource binding when you call `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView` in the Click handler.

Comment: I tryed to use a static Users property and I am sure I didn't do it right that is why I ask for help. Can you help me with some indications?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding to a function, which doesn't work. You should bind to a public property that contains a list of your models that you want to show in your datagrid. That way you need to move your `GetValues` call to somewhere else, but you allready have that code in your `LoadButton_Click` Event-Handler, so I would reuse that.

So the first change would be to change your `userCol`-Collection to a public property instead of a public field, because bindings only work on public properties, besides you want to raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` if the reference to the your `ObservableCollection` changes.

```
// old code
public static ObservableCollection<Userss> userCol = new ObservableCollection<Userss>();

// new Code
private static ObservableCollection<Userss> userCol = new ObservableCollection<Userss>();

public static ObservableCollection<Userss> UserCol {
   get { return userCol; }
   set { userCol = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Your `GetValues`-Method doesn't need a return type anymore, so just change it to void. Inside, change every call to `usercol` to the new public property `UserCol` so that if changes to the List happen, the GUI needs to now about it (via the `RaisePropertyChanged` e.g.)

Inside of your `LoadButton_Click` you are basically doing the same as in your `GetValues` function which also doesn't make much sense, especially because you don't use your `Userss` models anymore. You can instead just use the `GetValues`-Method here to reload all the data (also you would need another event e.g. DataGridLoaded or something to fill your data at startup):

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... exception handling
    Userss.GetValues();
}
```

Now simply bind to your collection in your xaml view:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGreen" Height="245" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Userss.UserCol, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Note that this is just the general idea and that I have not testet this code, so you maybe need to fix it in a view places. Also I think it would be good if you would look a bit into the MVVM design pattern to structure your code in a nice fashion.

Comment: Hello, Michael. I've tryed your way and when I press the `Update_Click' nothing is happening, I debugged my program and I saw that nothing is changing in `dataset` or `datatable`, and I don't understand why.
PS: I edited the `Update_Click` i added `Query = "Select * from user";
                    adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, m_db);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adap.Fill(ds, "Users");
                    dt = ds.Tables[0];`